# How to work out types required for std::for_each lambda function

Tags: c++11, lambda

I am confused about how to work out what type is required to use a lambda function in std::for_each.  It seems I cannot use auto in this case as a parameter (Visual Studio 2013 complains anyway).

In the code below I would have thought I would use sections as the type for the for_each function, but in fact I have to use

```
const std::pair<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> >
```

And for the 'inner' type in this case what do I use?

My main question is how I work out what type to use?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>


// key=value pairs within a section
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> keyvalue;

// [section1] - top level
typedef std::unordered_map< std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> > sections;

class config
{
public:
    config() {
        setup();
    }
    typedef sections::iterator iterator;
    iterator begin() { return sections_.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return sections_.end(); }


private:
    sections sections_;

    void setup() { 
        // obviously we wouldn't hard code like this in a real program
        sections_["programming languages"].insert(std::make_pair("C", "imperative"));
        sections_["programming languages"].insert(std::make_pair("C++", "OOP"));
        sections_["programming languages"].insert(std::make_pair("Java", "OOP"));
        sections_["programming languages"].insert(std::make_pair("Haskell", "functional"));
        sections_["programming languages"].insert(std::make_pair("Prolog", "logic"));
    }
};


int main() {
    config cfg;
    std::for_each(cfg.begin(), cfg.end(), [](const std::pair<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> > sec) {
        std::cout << "section name: " << sec.first << std::endl;

        // what is inner type - thought it would be keyvalue ???
        //std::for_each(sec.second.begin(), sec.second.end(), [](const keyvalue& pr) {   
            //std::cout << "first: " << pr << std::endl;
        //});
    });

    // I thought type would be sections ???
    //std::for_each(cfg.begin(), cfg.end(), [](const sections& sec) {
    //  std::cout << "section name: " << sec.first << std::endl;
    //});
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `for (auto &&sec : cfg)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `decltype` for this purpose like this:

```
    config cfg;
    std::for_each(cfg.begin(), cfg.end(), [](const decltype(*cfg.begin())& sec) {
        std::cout << "section name: " << sec.first << std::endl;

        std::for_each(sec.second.begin(), sec.second.end(), [](const decltype(*sec.second.begin())& pr) {   
        std::cout << "first: " << pr.first << std::endl;
        });
    });
```

I'm not 100% certain how reference types affect this, so removing it might be more appropriate like `const std::remove_reference<decltype(*cfg.begin())>::type& sec`

Although it should be noted that VS2013 ItelliSense has trouble with decltype and will mark it as an error even if it compiles fine.

STL containers always define a `value_type` so in that case you can use `decltype(inst)::value_type` and you don't need the remove_reference shenanigans. So I would advise you to also add a `value_type` typedef to your type like this:

```
class config
{
public:
    typedef sections::value_type value_type;
```

Then you can do:

```
    config cfg;
    std::for_each(cfg.begin(), cfg.end(), [](const decltype(cfg)::value_type& sec) {
        std::cout << "section name: " << sec.first << std::endl;

        std::for_each(sec.second.begin(), sec.second.end(), [](const decltype(sec.second)::value_type& pr) {   
        std::cout << "first: " << pr.first << std::endl;
        });
    });
```